# Overlay an image with text and buttons

Tags: html, css, web

I'm working on an image collage on a website and would like each image to have an overlay smoothly transition in whenever the user hovers over an image. This overlay should be slightly transparent and contain text and buttons. Here is my progress so far: http://classicopia.ivointeractive.com/

Each image is wrapped in a 'product' div and each product div should contain an img and a 'productOverlay' div that comes up on hover. Right now, the bookcase is the only item that has an overlay attached to it - you can't see it though, thats one of the problems

I am stuck on two problems right now:

1. How do I make the overlay visible? There are no rules making it invisible right now, the only thing I can do to see it is set its positioning to absolute, but that messes up its dimensions.
2. How can I get the overlay to actually be over the image? (Right now it gets placed below it)

I have jQuery loaded in already so any solutions using that would be fine too. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent div will need to be relative and the child div will need to be absolute or fixed. You will then need to add `top: 0;` and `left: 0;` as well as `z-index: 1;` to the CSS for the child div. Then use jQuery to show and hide on hover.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `z-index` css property.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap every image in a div with `position: relative` and put the overlay in this div as well.

The overlay is `display: none` at first. On mouse over the div you set `display: block` for the overlay. Or jQuery `show()` and `hide()`

The image has `z-index` of 0, the overlay has 1.

Comment: I tried this through creating a new div with position:relative and also just making 'product' divs relative, but neither made any difference

Comment: Well, what did you try? Make a jsfiddle.

Comment: I'm mobile at the moment. Cannot inspect your code. Make a jsfiddle of a single image and overlay. It will help us to help you.